Loacting town called Ocinovca or Osinocka in or near Russia in 1861
I am looking for a town called Ocinovca or Osinocka in or near Russia in 1861. Where my ancestors came from .
Can anyone tell me where this town was?
I think it was from the Turkistan or Kazakhstan area.

It sounds like "Osinovka" (Cyrillic Осиновка), which is a fairly common place name - from Осина (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Осина) (European aspen tree, a kind of poplar).
Moreover, after Central Asian countries became independent in the 1990s, many place named got changed from Russian to various local languages.
I googled and found several Osinovkas in that general area.  There are likely to be more.
https://www.getamap.net/maps/kazakhstan/almaty/_osinovka/ in Almaty region of Kazakhstan
http://www.maplandia.com/kazakhstan/taldy-kurgan/osinovka/
https://nona.net/features/map/placedetail.1880547/Osinovka/
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Осиновка_(Костанайская_область)
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Осиновка_(Восточно-Казахстанская_область)
There are many more in Russia, Belarus, and other regions:
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Осиновка
